# How to get eBay Item details using item gallery image URL

Tags: web-crawler, ebay-api

I am a dropshipper and i have list of eBay items image URLs (~200K), each image URL having unique ID in the URL itself. Any API call or other options to get corresponding item based on item image URL

Answer (score 0):

It depends which image URL you have. There is one that has the item number in the url, and there is one that is a random jumble of generated characters which you can only the other way (Item -> Image URL).

Comment: I've seen this too and wonder what it is. Item number hash perhaps? I wish there was a way to decode it.